# FFmpeg command using setpts and atempo options mismatch audio and video

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg, command

I want to speed up audio and video accurately.

When i execute this command, video generated successfully. But video still same as input video and audio speed up correctly, how to correct this issue.

my command for this scenario is:(I am implemented this in android)

```
-i, /storage/emulated/0/MP4_20171222_191425.mp4, \
-i, /data/user/0/22122017_071452.png, \
-i, /data/user/0/22122017_0714550.png, \
-filter_complex, [1:v]scale=185:187[ovr1];\
[2:v]scale=115:118[ovr2];\
[0:v][ovr1] overlay=x=336.68634:y=5.8838935 [tmp];\
[tmp][ovr2] overlay=x=110.51852:y=105.864914; \
[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];\
[0:a]atempo=2.0[a], \
-map, [v], \
-map, [a], \
-c:v, libx264, \
-c:a, aac, \
-r, 60, \
-preset, ultrafast, \
/storage/emulated/0/Vid_22122017_071455.mp4
```

What i am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the setpts to the processed video stream, so

```
...
[tmp][ovr2] overlay=x=110.51852:y=105.864914,setpts=0.5*PTS[v];\
[0:a]atempo=2.0[a], \
-map, [v], \
...
```